# Train object detection with large images

Tags: python-3.x, object-detection

Can I train the object detection model with large images size 1600*1216 and obtain good accuracy . Thanks

Comment: what issue do you face?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have already tried along with the specific issues you are facing

Comment: What makes you believe you could not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can train the object detection model with large images size 1600*1216 and obtain good accuracy.